# Using HMAC-Whirlpool in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, hmac, jce

My program has to use `HMAC-sha256` and `HMAC-whirlpool`. I use `javax.crypto` for the `HMAC-sha256` algorithm and it works without problems. But I got problems using `HMAC-whirlpool`. I only found whirlpool. Is there a way how I can use the whirlpool library and change it to become a `HMAC-whirlpool` algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HMacWhirpool class:

> This class implements the HMAC (Keyed-Hashing for Message
>   Authentication) algorithm as defined in RFC 2104 with WHIRLPOOL as
>   message digest algorithm.

Usage:

```
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HMAC/WHIRLPOOL");
hmac.init(secret_key);
 byte[] mac_data = hmac.doFinal(data);
```

You can find more info [here](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/security/mac/HMacWhirlpool.html)

Comment: You forgot the part where you show how to include the IAIK JCE in the code. Right now, this would still result in an exception.

Comment: @Pooya thank you for the fast answer. But I can't find a location where I can download this library. I only found this:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloadiaikjcejar.htm but there is no HMACWhirlpool class included.

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy visit https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/crm/registration.php and register for "educational use" license then you can download the library

Comment: @Pooya Thanks for the link. Do you know an alternative where the library is free even for commercial use?

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy sorry this is the extent of my knowledge on such a library